# QMutex with QThread - prime number sekeer

Tags: c++, qt, qt5, c++14

Hello I have the problem grasping qthread with qmutex - generally how to use it - to learn it I'm trying to create prime number seeker with limit to 8,000,000 but I am failing badly with it even if I base it with code given with similar examples - I don't really know what I have misunderstood but I've created one global variable and I'm passing it to two threads - in given code one thread is incrementing the variable and the second one is doing calculations - but it is not good solution - not in a long run - the code works up to 8000 so the speak is that I'm not sure if I ever got it right. Documentation is giving me only little grasp how to do it - the code samples are not very helpful.

I've tried:
- running it with code samples as basis 
- creating one loop in main thread what is crushing the program
- filtering the number that both threads won't collide

Here is the actual code: 
calculate object.h

```
#include <QObject>
#include <QThread>

class CalculateObject : public QThread
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    CalculateObject(QMutex *mu, int *nu);
    void run();
    bool isPrime(unsigned int);
    QMutex *mutex;
    int *counter;
    bool checker;
    QString name;
signals:
    void sendResult(int);
    void done();
};
```

calculate object.cpp

```
#include "calculateobject.h"
#include <QtMath>


const int LIMIT = 8000000;

CalculateObject::CalculateObject(QMutex *mu, int *nu)
{
    counter = nu;
    mutex = mu;
    checker = false;
}
bool CalculateObject::isPrime(unsigned int number)
{
    if(number > 3)
    {
        if (number % 2 == 0)
        {
            return false;
        }
        const unsigned int MAX = (unsigned int)sqrt(number) + 1;
        for (int i = 3;i < MAX; i += 2) {
            if((number % i) == 0)
            {
                return false;
            }
        }
       return true;
    }
    if(number < 2)
    {
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}
void CalculateObject::run()
{
    int result = 0;
    while(*counter < 8000)
    {
        QThread::usleep(5);
        if(this->name == "first")
        {
            mutex->lock();
            *counter += 1;
            qDebug() << *counter;
            mutex->unlock();
        }
        else {
            mutex->lock();
            checker = isPrime(*counter);
            mutex->unlock();
            if(checker == true)
            {
                result = 1;
                emit(sendResult(result));
            }

        }
    }
        emit(done());
}
```

calculatorwidget.h

```
#include <QWidget>
#include <QPushButton>
#include <QLabel>
#include "calculateobject.h"
#include <QThread>

class CalculatorWidget : public QWidget
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    explicit CalculatorWidget(QWidget *parent = nullptr);
    ~CalculatorWidget();
    CalculateObject *object, *object2;
public slots:
    void readResults(int counter);
    void startThread();
    void finishThread();
    void endMessage();
    void controller();
private:
    int reader;
    Ui::CalculatorWidget *ui;
    QPushButton *start;
    QLabel *resultReader;
    QThread *newProcess;
    QThread *newerProcess;
signals:
    void end();

};
```

calculatorwidget.cpp

```
#include "calculatorwidget.h"
#include "ui_calculatorwidget.h"
#include <QMessageBox>

int number = 0;
QMutex aMutex;

CalculatorWidget::CalculatorWidget(QWidget *parent) :
    QWidget(parent),
    ui(new Ui::CalculatorWidget)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);
    start = ui->start;
    resultReader = ui->result;
    newProcess = new QThread;
    newerProcess = new QThread;
    reader = 0;
    connect(start, &QPushButton::clicked, this, &CalculatorWidget::startThread);
}
void CalculatorWidget::controller()
{
    static int control = 0;
    control++;
    if(control == 2)
    {
        emit(end());
    }
}

CalculatorWidget::~CalculatorWidget()
{
    delete ui;
}
void CalculatorWidget::readResults(int counter)
{
    reader += counter;
}
void CalculatorWidget::startThread()
{
    int *count = &number;
    QMutex *mutex = &aMutex;
    object = new CalculateObject(mutex, count);
    object2 = new CalculateObject(mutex, count);
    connect(object, &CalculateObject::sendResult, this, &CalculatorWidget::readResults);
    connect(object2, &CalculateObject::sendResult, this, &CalculatorWidget::readResults);
    connect(object, &CalculateObject::done, this, &CalculatorWidget::controller);
    connect(object2, &CalculateObject::done, this, &CalculatorWidget::controller);
    connect(this, &CalculatorWidget::end, this, &CalculatorWidget::finishThread);
    object->name = "first";
    object2->name = "second";
    object->start();
    object2->start();

}
void CalculatorWidget::finishThread()
{
    newProcess->exit();
    newProcess->wait(3);
    newerProcess->wait(3);
    newerProcess->exit();
    endMessage();
}
void CalculatorWidget::endMessage()
{
    QMessageBox msg;
    msg.setText("The calculation Process is done" + QString::number(reader));
    msg.exec();
}
```

main.cpp

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication a(argc, argv);
    CalculatorWidget widget;
    widget.show();
    return a.exec();
}
```

ui file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ui version="4.0">
 <class>CalculatorWidget</class>
 <widget class="QWidget" name="CalculatorWidget">
  <property name="geometry">
   <rect>
    <x>0</x>
    <y>0</y>
    <width>400</width>
    <height>300</height>
   </rect>
  </property>
  <property name="windowTitle">
   <string>Form</string>
  </property>
  <layout class="QVBoxLayout" name="verticalLayout_2">
   <item>
    <layout class="QVBoxLayout" name="verticalLayout">
     <item>
      <widget class="QLabel" name="label">
       <property name="text">
        <string>This program calculates how many prime numbers </string>
       </property>
      </widget>
     </item>
     <item>
      <widget class="QLabel" name="label_2">
       <property name="text">
        <string>are in de spectrum from 0 to 8000000</string>
       </property>
      </widget>
     </item>
    </layout>
   </item>
   <item>
    <layout class="QHBoxLayout" name="horizontalLayout">
     <item>
      <widget class="QPushButton" name="start">
       <property name="text">
        <string>Start</string>
       </property>
      </widget>
     </item>
     <item>
      <widget class="QLabel" name="result">
       <property name="text">
        <string/>
       </property>
      </widget>
     </item>
    </layout>
   </item>
  </layout>
 </widget>
 <resources/>
 <connections/>
</ui>
```

I expect that my code will show me how many prime numbers are in spectrum from 0 to 8,000,000 but the program is hanging out or crushing

Comment: Please post a complete minimal reproducible example. I'm just not able to compile your program. There are missing includes and even worser the Ui file ist missing. I also think, that your program is far from being minimal. Remove as much as possible having still the same behavior. You should also consider to use `QMutexLocker` to make your code less error prone and easier to understand.

Comment: file included as weel headers

Comment: Extending QThread is generally bad practice. Check this page https://wiki.qt.io/QThreads_general_usage for an example. With this approach, you don't need mutexes in most cases.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't really know, what is really your problem, but you should try to use a `QMutexLocker` in the beginning auf the `run()` function. Just try if your program works safely then.

You should also keep in mind, that reading a shared variable must be also protected by a mutex. See also the post [QMutex needed to read variable](https://stackoverflow.com/q/16773515/5762796).

```
void CalculateObject::run()
{
    QMutexLocker lock(mutex);
    int result = 0;
    while(*counter < 8000)
    {
        //QThread::usleep(5);
        if(this->name == "first")
        {
            *counter += 1;
            qDebug() << *counter;
        }
        else {
            checker = isPrime(*counter);
            if(checker == true)
            {
                result = 1;
                emit(sendResult(result));
            }

        }
    }
    emit(done());
}
```

Please report, if this solved your issue.

Comment: Thanks Aleph0 for your time - your solution worked well  - I didn't think about qMutexLocker - this is when you are learning on your own. One more thanks.